# Changes to make when moving my VisualSVN Server to a new location (IP)

Tags: svn, version-control, visualsvn-server

I'm moving my VisualSVN Server and more importantly its IP.  What do I have to do to get the server talking to the clients at the new location?

I assume that I have to somehow setup port forwarding (I think virtual SVN is 8443) on the router but I believe this was handled automatically when I initially set it up, can I get it to automatically do it again?

I am using tortoise SVN on my clients and I found the "Relocate" feature so I should be good to get the clients working.

Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: I recommend you to use a public or private DNS entry to avoid using IP in the future (ie: svn.lan as 192.168..... for example, and svn.lan as your address in Tortoise SVN).

Comment: @ Parallelis, for security reasons or ease of use?